# Rails HAML conversion problems - unexpected kENSURE, expecting kEND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm trying to switch over to using HAML for my views but I keep getting unexpected KENSURE messages.  I've used html2haml to switch over working view files.   First run through it told me I didn't need the end that html2haml had in its output so I removed it and now I get errors that look like it is complaining about the form not being ended.

What am I doing wrong?

error message:

```
compile error
app/views/sessions/new.html.haml:20: syntax error, unexpected kENSURE, expecting kEND
app/views/sessions/new.html.haml:22: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND
```

application.html.haml:

```
!!!
%html
%head
  %title
    = APP_CONFIG[:site_name] + ': ' + @page_title  
  == <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8" />
  == <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no"  />
  == <meta name="distribution" content="all" />
  == <meta name="robots" content="all"  />
  == <meta name="resource-type" content="document" />
  == <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true"   />
  = stylesheet_link_tag 'base'
  = javascript_include_tag :defaults

  %body
    #container
      #header
        - if logged_in?
          = link_to 'Logout', logout_path
        - else
          = link_to 'Login', login_path
          = link_to 'Signup', signup_path
      #content
        = flash_messages
        = yield :layout
```

and sessions/new.html.haml

```
= title "Login", :h2
- form_tag session_path do
%fieldset
  %legend
    Your Details
  %ol
    %li
      = label_tag 'login', 'Username'
      = text_field_tag 'login', @login
    %li
      = label_tag 'password'
      = password_field_tag 'password', nil
    %li
      = label_tag 'remember_me', 'Remember me'
      = check_box_tag 'remember_me', '1', @remember_me
.buttons
  = submit_tag 'Login'
  = link_to 'Forgotten Password', forgot_password_path
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is something haml does when you've gotten your spacing wrong.  html2haml does most of the work for you, but you still have to review the changes.  The problem in sessions/new.html.haml is that you are starting a do block with no content:

```
- form_tag session_path do
%fieldset
```

The whole fieldset should be nested (indented) within that `do` block.  Because there's no content at all, haml fails to put in an `end` declaration, so when the file gets interpreted, you get:

```
unexpected $end, expecting kEND
```

meaning "I hit the end of the file ($end), I was expecting the end keyword (kEND)"

Comment: That's the solution but I think this debug session has completely put me off of HAML. Closing a few brackets is inconsequential compared to having to deal with inscrutable whitespace parsing errors. The button class also needed to be indented as well and the meta tags are borked by HTML2HAML by being converted to ruby hashes. Too many strange quirks in this DSL for my liking

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I'd second Mike Woodhouse's suggestion to try converting files by hand - the whitespace stuff does get instinctive pretty quickly. Even if you do abandon Haml, though, it looks like you've found some bugs in html2haml, so I'd love to see your input files so I can fix them.

Answer (score 1):

As shown, the first chunk has %body indented one level more than %head, and %head at the same level as %html, neither of which is good. If it works, you may get something like

```
<html>
</html>
<head>
  ...
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</head>
```

I think most browsers will choke on that! ;-)

In general I'm not a fan of html2haml, which although it tries hard doesn't seem to be able to handle everything. Unless you have a seriously large pile of view files, I'd be inclined to spend the time reworking the files by hand. You don't have to do them all at once, why not just translate them as you go? You'll learn a lot more about HAML that way, too. Enough that - hopefully - you'll find the whole indentation thing becomes instinctive, after which progress begins to accelerate.

Answer (score 1):

HAML behaves really poorly with problems like tabs instead of whitespace, and incorrect indentation.

My workaround (at least on OSX using TextMate) is to use TextMate, have the [HAML/SASS bundle installed](http://bjhess.com/blog/2007/05/31/installing-haml-bundle-for-textmate/). Then I use CMD-[ to un-indent the text, following by CMD-] to re-indent the text properly. That gets rid of any invisible tabs and incorrect indentation, plus reveals any structural problems.

Answer (score 0):

One underused feature is the ERB mode of html2haml.

```
html2haml -e < input.html > output.html.haml
```

Just using -e will get your HAML about 95% of the way there rather than 50% using pure html2haml